# oracle sql varray contains an element

Tags: oracle, plsql, varray

I have a type declaration like this:

```
  FUNCTION ...
  IS 
     TYPE stati_va IS VARRAY (10000) OF varchar(1);
     stati       stati_va;
     v_counter   INTEGER  := 0;
  BEGIN
      stati := stati_va ();

      --this is actually in a loop so the array contains more values
      v_counter := v_counter + 1;
      stati.EXTEND;
      stati (v_counter) := '4';


      --here I would like to determine if the array 'stati' contains a value
```

I have tried the following so far but that gives me an errro

```
      IF '4' member of stati then  <- COMPILE error
      IF '4' IN stati then         <- COMPILE error
```

I know that looping through the array would be possible but that is a bit inconvinient since I need to build something like this:

```
     IF array contains '4' then
     elsif array contains '3' then
     elseif array contains '2' then
     ...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the condition:

```
IF 'element' member OF <my_array> THEN
```

For example,

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2  TYPE v_array
  3  IS
  4    TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
  5    my_array v_array;
  6  BEGIN
  7    my_array := v_array('1','2','3','4');
  8    IF '4' member OF my_array THEN
  9      dbms_output.put_line('yes');
 10    ELSE
 11      dbms_output.put_line('no');
 12    END IF;
 13  END;
 14  /
yes

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it with a VARRAY without looping through it.

It is possible to accomplish with associative table:

`DECLARE
    TYPE stati_va IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY binary_integer;
    l_array stati_va;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. 1000
    LOOP
        l_array(i) := dbms_random.random;
    END LOOP;`

```
IF (l_array.exists(4))
THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(l_array(4));
END IF;

IF (l_array.exists(234234))
THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('index exists');
ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('index doesnt' exist');
END IF;
```

END;
/

You can use binary_integer or varchar2 as keys to this array, anything as value

**Edit:**
I have forgotten *member* syntax. Since it behaves strangely in sql (select statements) we have banned it in our team

it would be (with varray or nested table) 
if key member of array then ...